# I tried to download this geocode data

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, url

Basically I am accessing this URL

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sudirman&sensor=true&bounds=-7.186696,105.7727|-5.186696,107.7727

However, the result is empty. Even though it should show something. I used objective-c

With this code:

```
response= [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlresponse error:&error];

json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I think the | need to be urlencoded. How to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate. See [How to encode a URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlresponse error:&error];
```

returns NSData, which when serialised will produce JSON, so you need to do:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

to get the JSON.